# Rectifier diode failure not showing on multimeter diode test

Tags: power-supply, diodes

A rectifier diode [RM3](https://dtsheet.com/doc/1431597/rm3---rm3c-silicon-rectifier-diodes-prv---400---1000) failure is not showing on diode [test](https://www.fluke.com/en-gb/learn/blog/condition-monitoring/how-to-test-diodes-using-a-digital-multimeter). I get the usual around 600mV and blocking (OL) in the other direction on the multimeter diode test. Also I tried connecting to a 15V supply to see if it is still blocking - no current flows. So according to the meter the diode is good. The output of the rectifier should be around 15V normally.

I desoldered this diode and replaced it with a new one and the circuit rectifies just fine.

So I was wondering what kind diode failure is possible that does not show on the static diode test yet shows under circuit conditions?

Any explaination would be good even an article or book on faults like this.

Comment: You tested it in circuit?  Test it again now that it is out of the circuit.

Comment: @JRE I had tried to be sure and the meter said it was good.

Comment: What is an RM3 failure?

Comment: @Brian Drummond Rm3 is the diode model

Comment: Don't put on blinders.    Perhaps the diode is just fine, but it was soldered down poorly.   Changing the diode fixed the problem, but not for the reason you think.   (I don't know this, just presenting an alternate theory).  People tend to get focused on "this must be the problem" without looking for other possibilities....

Comment: The 600mV reported is probably at a very low current (few mA) as that's what the meter outputs.  Perhaps your 'real' circuit drives WAY more current and the diode can't handle that.

Comment: @Kyle B unfortunately I assumed this was true too and put it back and then it did not work again yesterday. I suppose its fixed with a new diode thats good but I was more interested in whether there are dynamic faults that do not show on a multimeter diode test. I've assumed probably not knowing enough that a multimeter test is all that is needed.